# How to customize Silverstripe login page content?

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe `3.5.3`  I want to customize content (`$Content`) of the `Security/login` page. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the OP asked specifically for its theme, but in case someone wants to know how to do it on the code side of things, you can use the request object to determine that, like this:

*/mysite/code/Page.php*

```
public function anyMethod() {

    $value = 'default';

    if (Controller::curr()->getRequest()->getURL() === 'Security/login') {
        $value = 'something else';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

*(On SilverStripe 4.1.0, anyway)*

Answer (score 10):

You can also modify the page template by putting a template file named **Security_login.ss** in your **templates/Layout** directory.

The contents of one i've used in a previous project is:

```
<div class="row security-spacer">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>$Title</h1>
        <div class="typography">$Content</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                $Form
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also create templates for

- Security_changepassword.ss
- Security_lostpassword.ss
- Security_passwordsent.ss

Comment: Greate! Thank you Gavin!

Answer (score 4):

You could extend the `LoginForm` class and create your own `LoginForm` anyway you like. You could base it off of the `MemberLoginForm.php` class.

Check out [this](http://tamethebackbutton.blogspot.ca/2009/09/customize-your-own-silverstripe-login.html) article here which may help.

Comment: Thank you Pavel! Your answer helped me. Спасибо!